# Fixing the error - cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object in a DBT macro using Jinja

Tags: dbt

I am writing a macro that uses Snowflake to offload a prebuilt table to an s3 bucket. Normally, we just have one table but in this instance I have 5 or 6 tables to unload into the same s3 bucket. I was writing a for loop to iterate through a list of a dictionary with the file being the name of the file being written to s3 and the table being the table to unload in Snowflake. The code works, but I keep getting an error after the unloading of `cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` which makes me think that the loop is trying to run one last time.

The code I have is as follows:

```
{% macro send_anaplan_data_to_s3() %}
    {{ log('Running Export to S3 Macro ...', info = true) }}
    {% set table_names=[{"file":" '/file_name.csv' ", "table":"DATABSE.SCHEMA.TABLE"}] %}

    {% for name in table_names %}
  {{ log(name.file, info = true) }}
  {{ log(name.table, info = true) }}
-----first table-----
     -- this block makes the s3 path with dated filename
    {%- call statement('send_s3_statement', fetch_result=True) -%}
    select concat('s3://data-anaplan',{{ name.file }})
    {%- endcall -%}


    -- first compiles then executes against db
    -- so we need if/else otherwise it will fail on
    -- compile when accessing .data[0]
    {%- if execute -%}
    
    {%- set result = load_result('send_s3_statement').data[0] -%}
      
    {%- else -%}

    {%- set result = [] -%}
        
    {%- endif -%}

    -- spot check the resulting filename.
    {{ log('resulting filename:', info=True )}}
    {{ log(result, info=True )}}

    -- send the data to the correct location in S3
    {% for r in result -%}
        {{ log(r, info=true) }}
        {{ log('Unloading to s3', info = true) }}
        {%- call statement(auto_begin=true) -%}

            COPY INTO '{{r}}' from {{ name.table }}
            STORAGE_INTEGRATION = S3_SNOWFLAKE_ANAPLAN_INTEGRATION
            SINGLE = TRUE
            MAX_FILE_SIZE = 4900000000
            OVERWRITE = TRUE
            FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV, FIELD_DELIMITER = ',', FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"', COMPRESSION = NONE, NULL_IF=())
            HEADER = TRUE
        {%- endcall -%}
            
        {%- if not loop.last -%} , {%- endif %}

    {% endfor -%}

    -- confirm when done
    {{log('Finished.', info=True)}}

    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Any ideas here? Thank you!

Comment: you can handle this using `{% if columnList is none  %}{% set columnList = [] %}{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

This error implies that one of the queries you pass to the db is empty/null. Check the db logs to see where that's happening.